# Should SQLite typeof() work with SQL as well?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net, sqlite

To get a columns' DataType I'm using following code in C#

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection con = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("Data Source=C:\\Users\\SaMax\\Documents\\CustomersDB.s3db; Version=3; FailIfMissing=True;");
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand cmd = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand("select typeof(Column_Name) from Table_Name;");
cmd.Connection = con;

try
{
    con.Open();
    string str = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show(str);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

It works. But I was wondering if it's OK, and OK for SQL, MySql as well.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if it's OK

Hard to tell without knowing your intentions, but unless your are coding something highly dynamic the chances are that you already know before-hand what is the type of the column. Why are you running this query?

> and OK for SQL

It is not standard SQL, it's a function specific to SQLite. Other SQL flavors might have something similar to obtain the type of a column, but you can't use that same SQL string and expect it to work on any database.

Comment: I'm running this query simply to get the datatype of specified column
returned in string.

Comment: Ok. Then you'll have to change your SQL for each type of database you query.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. One last questions is: any alternative function
to SQLite typeof() exist in sql so I can use same query for most database?

Comment: @samaxI92 You can't do it in pure SQL because checking the type of a column is not part of the SQL standard and each SQL implementation does this feature in a different way (if at all). You might have a chance if you use an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) instead of hard-coding SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

For `SQL-Server`

Try This:

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where   
  TABLE_NAME='Product' and COLUMN_NAME='Id'
```